# Update redux state in two places with one action

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, shopping-cart

I am building a webshop and I´ve run in to some problems. When I click on the buy button I want three things to happen:

- Add the product to the redux state (shoppingcartReducer)
- Update the sum and quantity in the redux state (shoppingcartReducer)
- Render out the sum and quantity in my shoppingCart.js
  component

The problem is in the shoppingcartReducer. I dont know how to update the state in two different paths on one action.

```
return state
            .setIn(['products', action.articleNr], addArticle(action, state))
```

Here I am in the 'products/articleNr' path and manipulating data, but I also wants to update the sum and quantity in './'.

So my alternatives that I thought of are maybe to have some sort of middleware thing in the shoppingcartActions but I don´t really know if this is right, nor how to do it!

I appreciate all the help, thanks!

---

**shoppingcartReducer:**

```
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable'

import { addToShoppingcart, createShoppingCart } from '../actions/shoppingcartActions'

const ADD_TO_SHOPPINGCART = 'ADD_TO_SHOPPINGCART'
const CREATE_SHOPPING_CART = 'CREATE_SHOPPING_CART'

const initialState = Immutable({
  sum: 0,
  quantity: 0
})

export default function shoppingcartReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_SHOPPINGCART:
      return state
        .setIn(['products', action.articleNr], addArticle(action, state))

    case CREATE_SHOPPING_CART:
      return state
        .set(action.id, createCart(action))
  }
  return state
}

function addArticle(action, state) {
  return {
    product: action.product
  }
}

function createCart(action) {
  return {
    id: action.id,
  }
}
```

**shoppingcartActions:**

```
let nextTodoId = 0

const ADD_TO_SHOPPINGCART = 'ADD_TO_SHOPPINGCART'
const CREATE_SHOPPING_CART = 'CREATE_SHOPPING_CART'

export function addToShoppingcart(product) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TO_SHOPPINGCART,
    articleNr: product.articleNr,
    product: product,
  }
}

export function createShoppingCart() {
  return {
    type: CREATE_SHOPPING_CART,
    id: 'productNr:'+nextTodoId++,
  }
}
```

**ShoppingCart.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as shoppingcartActions from '../../actions/shoppingcartActions'

class ShoppingCart extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.state = {
      shoppingcartReducer: []
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {  
    this.setState({
      shoppingcartReducer: nextProps.shoppingcartReducer ? nextProps.shoppingcartReducer : ''
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { shoppingcartReducer } = this.props
    const { sum, quantity } = shoppingcartReducer

    return (
      <div className="shoppingCart">
          <ul>
            <li>Summa: {sum} :-</li>
            <li>Antal varor: {quantity}</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    shoppingcartReducer: state.shoppingcartReducer
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(shoppingcartActions, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShoppingCart)
```

Comment: It's very easy in redux for one action to trigger muliple state changes. You just use multiple reducers handling the same action. Do you use [`combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html)?

Comment: Multiple reducers worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This worked!

```
export function addProduct(product) {
  return {
    type: ADD_PRODUCT,
    articleNr: product.articleNr,
    product: product,
  }
}

export function addSummary(product) {
  return {
    type: ADD_SUMMARY,
    product: product
  }
}

export function addToShoppingcart(product) {
    return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch( addProduct(product))
            dispatch( addSummary(product))
    }
}
```